# nodejs + postgresql way too slow

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have this piece of code:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var QueryStream = require('pg-query-stream');
var constr = 'postgres://devel:1234@127.0.0.1/tcc';
var JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
var http = require('http');

pg.connect(constr, function(err, client, done) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Erro ao conectar cliente.', err);
        process.exit(1);
    }

    sql = 'SELECT \
          pessoa.cod, \
          pessoa.nome, \
          pessoa.nasc, \
          cidade.nome AS cidade \
          FROM pessoa, cidade \
          WHERE cidade.cod IN (1, 2, 3);';

    http.createServer(function (req, resp) {
        resp.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html; Charset=UTF-8' });
        var query = new QueryStream(sql);
        var stream = client.query(query);

        //stream.on('data', console.log);
        stream.on('end', function() {
            //done();
            resp.end()
        });
        stream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(resp);
    }).listen(8080, 'localhost');
});
```

When I run apache bench on it, it get only about four requests per second.
If I run the same query in php/apache or java/tomcat I get ten times faster
results. The database has 1000 rows. If I limit the query to about ten rows,
then node is double faster than php/java.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: Some time ago I opened an issue here: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/653

I'm providing this link because I posted there some other variations on the code I have tried.
Even with comments and hints so far, I have not been able to get a descent speed.

Comment: Are all of your clients sharing the same connection to the database?  If that is the case, your requests may be serialized.  I am not sure this code properly utilizes the connection pool.

Comment: @Brandon, yes, they are. I also tried [this example from node-postgres documentation](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Example), but the results were about the same.

Comment: @FernandoBasso, first of all, i don't really use any kind of sql database, but from what i read about querystream, it only keeps a low number of rows in memory. so i think the bottleneck is querystream, you could try doing it without querystream

Comment: Yes, you should do a benchmark without streaming because with PHP/apache you do not stream the query result I guess.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - you are not joining the 2 tables. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Jayadevan No. Not intentional. I was so concerned with my main problem that I didn't notice that. Thanks for calling my attention to it.

Answer (score 6):

- [`pg-query-stream`](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-query-stream) uses cursors.
- it uses **cursors** (bold for emphasis).
- you can read the code and change `batchSize` to better fit your needs.

For those who don't know what cursors are, in short they are a trade-off for keeping memory footprint small and not reading a whole table in memory. But if you get `100` rows at a time when you have `1000` results, that's `1000 / 100` round-trips; so probably `10x` slower than a solution not using cursors.

If you know how many rows you need, add a `limit` to your query, and change the number of rows returned each time to minimize number of roundtrips.

Comment: @giladmayani, are you saying that part of the answer is rude? Can you please detail what part? I will fix it.

Comment: I find the part where you repeat "it uses **cursors**" 2 extra times to be rude, sounds sarcastic.

Comment: You are mistaking emphasis for rudeness / sarcasm; but I tweaked the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from this code, you create a single one connection to the PostgreSQL and everything gets queued through it.

The `pg` module allows for this, it's described here:
https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Queryqueue

If you want a real performance, the for each HTTP request you should fetch the connection from the pool, use it, release it and make 101% sure you always release (e.g. proper exception handling) or your server will die once the pool gets completely exhausted.

Once you are there you can tweak the connection pool parameters and measure performance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're waiting for the server to be created before the request gets relayed. Try moving http.createServer outside of the call. If you only want to use the http server in the request, you should try making the calls async.

Comment: nodejs is asynchronous iirc, also, moving the http.createServer outside the `pg.connect` would break it cause it use the variable name `client` which is gotten from `pg.connect`

Comment: @freeforalltousez It's async by default, but code inside of a call needs to use the async package. As of right now the code reads 1) Connect to pg, 2) query, 3) create server, pipe stream.

Comment: and here i thought the code reads 1) connect to pg, 2) create server and listen to port, 3) query when client (browser) connect to server, pipe stream

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should set http.agent.maxSockets value, try this:

```
var http = require('http');
http.agent.maxSockets = {{number}};
```

default maxSockets is 5